# Add a compose key sequence

Tags: shortcut-keys

I would like to add some compose key sequences in ubuntu 19.04, but .XCompose is being ignored. I need this as I type a lot of text with German Umlaut characters for which the compose key sequence is too slow on a UK keyboard.